# Using MVC .Net Core Tag Helpers in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, tag-helpers

Tag Helpers are a nice substitute for HTML Helpers in ASP.NET. Code is much easier to read when they're employed. To my knowledge, they're available in ASP.NET Core MVC.

Is it possible to use tag helpers in `ASP.NET 4.x MVC 5`? If so, then how do I go about doing it?

If not, is there a way to write code to create your own tag helpers for `ASP.NET 4.x MVC 5`?

Comment: Short answer - No and No.

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's a bummer.

Comment: If you use the nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers v1.x it might work, but I haven't tried it

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicated of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49452470/is-there-any-way-to-use-taghelpers-in-asp-net-mvc-5). See the answer below.

> No, tag helpers are only supported in ASP.NET Core, not in the older ASP.NET (based on the classic .NET Framework, rather than the newer .NET Core). But instead you can use [HTML Helpers](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/html-helpers-in-Asp-Net-mvc/) which do a lot of the same things.