# is there any way to use TagHelpers in asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Just wanted to utilize the new **tag helpers** in our 'legacy' asp.net mvc projects because they can help a lot for us I belive.

Installed **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers** nuget package but I'm stuck here since lacking of **@addTagHelper** feature so tag helpers not being processed runtime az all :(

Is it possible to set up solution/razor engine to use it somehow?

Comment: No, but you can use the standard HTML Helpers which do a lot of the same things. And ASP.NET (non-code) MVC is absolutely not "legacy", it's still fully supported with no roadmap to end that, and so is WebForms for that matter.

Comment: thank you for your response. Could you please elaborate more on "No"?  What is missing exactly from non-.core MVC razor engine?
The main reason why I intended to use tag helpers is that the mixture of razor and html syntax causes more small bugs runtime and being very disruptive when reading by humans.Html helpers dont solve this problem.

Comment: The older Razor engine simply doesn't understand them. It isn't looking for them and has no idea what to do with them. So what is missing (I assume, I haven't studied it in detail myself), is the code which detects the tag helpers in the markup and acts on them. I'm pretty sure it's all open-source so you could probably compare and contrast the two engines if you really wanted to. But I imagine it would be fairly challenging to backport the feature into the older MVC.

Comment: I agree that the tag-helper syntax is a lot neater and less verbose than the Razor HTML helper syntax, and that's probably why Microsoft changed to using it. But if you're using the older MVC I'm afraid you're probably stuck with the older style of syntax too.

Comment: If you decide to add support for tag helpers to MVC 5, please be sure to open source the implementation and post it on NuGet. I am sure others would like to "future-proof" their MVC 5 applications so they can more easily be ported to ASP.NET Core later.

Comment: @ADyson you should add your comment as an answer. Thanks to you I understood that TagHelpers are only for ASP.NET Core and that they can't be used with ASP.NET MVC "standard", and you provided a solution by suggesting to use HTML helpers instead.

Comment: @MichaëlPolla done :-)

Answer (score 6):

No, tag helpers are only supported in ASP.NET Core, not in the older ASP.NET (based on the classic .NET Framework, rather than the newer .NET Core).

But instead you can use [HTML Helpers](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/html-helpers-in-Asp-Net-mvc/) which do a lot of the same things.